# angular bootstrap tooltips not appearing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

This is my code:

```
.directive('mydir', function mydir() {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.attr('tooltip', 'hello');
            });
        }
    };
})
;
```

When the html renders, the tooltip attribute is present on it, but the tooltip does not appear on hover. But, if I hardcode the tooltip attribute onto the element, the tooltip appears on hover. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you add the tooltip like this ``elem.tooltip({title: 'hello'})``, there is no need to set the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

@Betty St said you need to provide option inside tooltip function, you shouldn't set the attribute & use `compile` function while scope isn't required as per your code.

**CODE**

```
.directive('mydir', function mydir() {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function(elem, attrs) {
                elem.tooltip({title: 'hello'});
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks.